# What is bizXpress? And what is the purpose and use of it in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am newer with WordPress, so i dont have enough knowledge of it. Last few days i have installed wordpress with Xampp. I also have created some post, pages.

But yesterday i was googling about WP then i got something about [bizXpress](http://www.bizxpress.com/), then i know about that. [bizXpress](http://www.bizxpress.com/) provides some tools, keywords for our website, which makes our website popular.

So i have followed this link:

http://wordpress.org/plugins/bizxpress/

http://www.nickusborne.com/if-you-have-a-wordpress-website-get-yourself-the-new-bizxpress-plugin/

I have installed bizXpress in WordPress. But i'm not able use. i have googled but cannot find anything usefull.

In these links, i found there are some tools and research tools to make website Popular.

but i dont have any idea how to use them.

Someone suggest me:

What is the purpose and use of bizXpress with Wordpress?
How can i use these tools with WordPress?

Comment: How bizXpress works isn't a programming question; you should ask **them** what's the purpose and use of **their** plugin

Comment: @DamienPisy- Yes its not a programming question, and also yes. i want to know the purpose and use of it?Please tell me, how do i start working with this?

Comment: Well i really dont know what is the reason behind down vote for this question.. something what i dont know about, looking for here. And i got a down vote Thanks Man

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The missing link in Wordpress is the guidance for how to turn a website into an online business. You need to do keyword research, and understand the process of, not just getting visitors, but turning them into customers. That's what bizXpress does. It teaches you the correct process (or one of them).

Yes you can find some help if you search around, but bizXpress builds it into the fabric of Wordpress via a plugin. After all, the best part of Site Build It is the guidance it gives to beginners. Sitesell is just offering that guidance to WP users.

Comment: You have turned me ON with this simple and soft answer. Thank you very much Rick Hart.

Answer (score 0):

To use those tools, in your admin, look for the name same as the name of the Plugin and you can manage it. :P Simple?

Comment: `I have installed bizXpress in WordPress.` Looks like OP already did that; OP's not asking on how to install it, but how it works.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand the question, but to me it seems OP just wants to know what's the use of the plugin, an information he can and **should** get on their website, since SO isn't bizXpress Help Desk

Comment: thats what i am looking from past few days but cannot find the exact way to use it, please tell me more with some more info.. thanks

Answer (score 0):

This plugin offers no functionality in WordPress. The plugin just creates a dashboard for links to the tools. It is easier to login at the bizxpress website instead of installing it on your site. The instruction manual is called the Action Guide.